# Is dllexport needed in the source C dll to be able to be used in c# with [DllImport]?

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

I am trying to write a wrapper functions around C.dll ( pbmman32.dll, if someone is familiar with it ) to use with c#.

Looking at the header files of the source, it doesn't seem that they implement `__declspec(dllexport)` although they do use `extern "C"{}`. Can i still call functions within that dll with the dllexport line missing?

For example:

```
BOOL PBM_Version (TCHAR* Buffer, WORD* Version, DWORD Size)
```

into:

```
[DllImport("pbmman32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool PBM_Version(StringBuilder Buffer, StringBuilder Version, System.UInt32 Size);
```

Comment: I would naively think that it works (except maybe the `StringBuilder` part for a `WORD*` variable, which probably should be something like `ref ushort`), have you tried it?

Comment: The point of creating a DLL is to export functions from it.  More than one way to do it.  Simply use the Visual Studio Command Prompt and run dumpbin.exe /exports pbmman32.dll and you'll see what is exported.  Do ask the vendor for a .NET wrapper, you are liable to get yourself into trouble.

Comment: Can't try it yet, the card which this driver talks to is not in place yet.  How is tchar* and word* different so that i have to pass the ref instead of just another stringbuilder tho?

Answer (score 1):

The `__declspec(dllexport)` is a convenient way to mark functions as exportable but it's not the only way (for instance they might have been exported using a .def file.

You should be able to query a DLL to get all the exported functions (you could use something like http://www.dependencywalker.com/). If the one you want to call is exported then you're good to go.

Comment: This is what i get from running that tool:       [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/FZejCM9.jpg). It seems to list the functions that in there. I see there is an entry point column. Is that entry point needed to be specified in the DLLImport?  @MikeDinescu

Comment: Yes, you should look for the function you'd like to call in that list.

Answer (score 0):

The vendor might have supplied a header file for you to use when importing rather than the version they used to build the DLL. More likely is that they exported the functions with a .def file. But there's no compulsion to use `__declspec(dllexport)`. Stop worrying about its absence.

I am sceptical of your translation though. The second parameter is probably an unsigned 2 byte type, passed as an out param. Declare it like this:

```
out ushort version
```

Decode the major version number with `version >> 8` and the minor with `version & 0xff`.

It's not enough to read the header file alone. You must read the documentation too.

The other area which gives cause for concern is the use of `TCHAR`. Does the library really offer ANSI and Unicode exports?